# Android AudioTrack get effective buffer size when api level < 23

Tags: java, android, audio, audiotrack

I am using the Android AudioTrack api to stream a wave file.

I had observed that the actual buffer size of the AudioTrack was not actually the size I specified in construction.

Because of this, I was using the method [getBufferSizeInFrames()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack#getBufferSizeInFrames())

This would provide me with the effective buffer size. I could then use this to create and write buffers of audio.

But when I tried to run my app on a device with api < 23, I discovered that this method is not supported. After scouring the api, I can not find another means to get the actual buffer size of the AudioTrack.

I am hoping I missed something, because I am rather confused. Is there a way to get the effective buffer size of an AudioTrack pre api 23?

Comment: why do you want that buffer size for?

Comment: Becuase the actual created buffer size does not seem to correspond with the requested buffer size sent to the ctor. I need to know the effective buffer size to figure out how many samples I can write without getting a short transfer count or a blocking call.

Comment: simply use `WRITE_BLOCKING` mode and write as much as you can - make a background `Thread` and `write` your data to your `AudioTrack` in a tight loop

Comment: I don't want to write as much as I can. I want to keep tight tabs on my buffer size and how much audio is in the buffer. I don't want to increase input latency on my app.